# AJAX Download file from LAN

Tags: ajax, download

I am working on a web application and the files that are being created and then downloaded are being saved on the file server of our LAN rather than the webserver.

when using the code below, this gets the right information for the file(s) I want to download, however open them directly rather than giving me the option to download.

Code.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "SubmissionTracker.aspx/ExportFile",
                data: JSON.stringify(params),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {

                    $("." + excel).show();
                    $("." + loader).hide();
                    //window.location.href = data.d;
                    window.location.replace(data.d);

                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log("error :" + data);
                    console.log(data);
                    $("." + excel).show();
                    $("." + loader).hide();
                }
            });
```

I would be most grateful if someone could help me force this to give me a save option so that the downloaded file doesn't just open.

As once the user has done this they will be manually attaching this file to an email that will be going outside of the business.

Any and all help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found my only way of doing it which was to change the value of a hidden link like so

```
$("#hiddenLink").attr("href", data.d);
console.log($("#hiddenLink").val());
$("#hiddenLink").click();
```